# T-SQL - Scripting variable not defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to `T-SQL` and I'm trying to backup my databases (using SQL Server 2008).

When I try to run the script via `sqlcmd -i inputfile` I got this error messages:
`'DATE' Scripting variable not defined`.

The problem is I have a line like this:
...`TO DISK = "FileName_$(ESCAPE_NONE(DATE)).BAK"` ...
With a date in a filename, it will prevent it from replacing my old backups.

If I run it in management studio, it works, but if I run it in command line with the `sqlcmd -i` command, then it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

I looked at the job history and I saw this error message:

> > "For SQL Server 2005 SP1 or later, you must use the appropriate ESCAPE_xxx
> >     macro to update job steps containing tokens before the job can run"

I don't quite understand what that means. I've already used `$ESCAPE_NONE(DATE)`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know but this is one of the first results and if anyone else has the same problem the answer isn't particularly easy to find.

Including the -x switch to disable environment variables fixed the problem for me;

```
sqlcmd -x -i inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to backup your sql server databases and append the date to them using sqlcmd there's an easy thing you can try.

First, create the sp called sp_BackupDabases which you can find here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698

You can invoke it from sql cmd using some command like this:

```
sqlcmd -U Damieh -P ilovechocolate -S (local) -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases  @backupLocation ='C:\MyBackups\', @BackupType='F'"
```

I'm sure you know this already, but just in case: -U is the user, -P is password, -S is server, and -Q is query. You can either backup all of your databases or some of them, there are parameters for that. You can find the stored proc parameters details on the same link I gave you.

**The date will be automatically appended** and you can play with the sp's code if you want it in a different place/way/format. I use this regularly on servers which don't have a non-express sqlserver (meaning that I can't schedule backups without using a .bat and task scheduler) with great success.

I apologize if this wasn't the answer you were looking for =). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming along late on this thread, but you can use the following:

```
SQLCMD -S YourServer -E -d YourDatabase -i YourScript 2> nul
```

That will send the StdErrorOut to the bit bucket.